# Jquery ajax addClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First sorry im a big beginner and just experimenting, and I made a similar wall like facebook with oembed.

And would like to add a like, and dislike button too.

I started with the like button, it works, likes, and unlikes too, and the cookie saves the class value perfectly.

My problems is the ajax call, so actually when I click on the like button it overwrites all anchors href val and adds a class to all not on what click.

here is my code

**jquery**

```
var cookieLike = "like_"
$('a.like').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href'), cookieLiked = cookieLike + id;

    switch($.cookies.get(cookieLiked) ) {
        case "unliked":
            $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        break;
        case "liked":
            $(this).addClass('btn-success');
        break;
    }
}).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var likeId = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>stream/like/" + likeId ,
        type: "post",
        data: likeId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(like)
        {

            if(like.likeStatus == "unliked") {
                $('a.like').attr('href', likeId).removeClass('btn-success');
                $.cookies.set(cookieLike + likeId, 'unliked');

            }else if(like.likeStatus == "liked") {
                $('a.like').attr('href', likeId).addClass('btn-success');
                $.cookies.set(cookieLike + likeId, 'liked');

            }

        }
    });

});
```

**html**

```
<div class="stream-bottom">
    <a href="#" class=" btn btn-mini comment">Komment</a>
    <div class="pull-right like-options">
        <a href="<?php echo $sp->sid; ?>" class=" btn btn-mini like"><i class="icon-thumbs-up" title="tetszik"></i> </a>
        <a href="<?php echo $sp->sid; ?>" class=" btn btn-mini dislike"><i class="icon-thumbs-down" title="nem tetszik"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

could please someone point out what i am missing?

Comment: And what is the behavior you're expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this);
    var likeId = button.attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>stream/like/" + likeId,
        type: "post",
        data: likeId,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (like) {
            if (like.likeStatus == "unliked") {
                button.removeClass('btn-success');
                $.cookies.set(cookieLike + likeId, 'unliked');
            } else if (like.likeStatus == "liked") {
                button.addClass('btn-success');
                $.cookies.set(cookieLike + likeId, 'liked');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Bind the target element (the clicked link) and reference it in the success callback

In the .on('click') callback

```
var $link = $(this);
```

In the success callback use

```
$(this).attr('href', likeId)
```

instead of

```
$('a.like').attr('href', likeId)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but the likeId is equal to $(this).attr('href'); so i dont think i need that $(this) in the success, or maybe im stupid, still tried it but nothing happens

Comment: @SperanskyDanil `this` refers to the target element on which the current event was fired. It is the object which you reference as `button` in your suggested code.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil you're correct. My mistake. $(this) needs to be referenced outside the context of the the callback

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("a")` or `$("a.like")` you are referring to the **entire** set of anchor tags or anchor tags with 'like' as the class name. To specifically use the anchor tag on which you have clicked use $(this) variable.

That will give you the element on which the event got generated and in this case the anchor tag on which you clicked.